# Is my answer wrong? Disproving a statement [Discrete Math]

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am asked to disprove the following statement:

For all integers n,m; if n > m, $n^2 - m^2$ is a prime number.

To answer this, I first wrote a negation of the above statement: There exist two integers n,m with n > m, such that $n^2 - m^2$ is not a prime number.

Then I gave a counterexample: n = 5, m = 4.

I was given half-credit for not providing a proof/not showing work.

Comment: For me your answer was correct.

Comment: In a low-level course I might have taken off *some* credit, since you didn’t actually demonstrate that $5^2-4^2$ is not prime, but giving only half credit seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Why did you not just take $m=0$ and any $n>0$ ?

Comment: I didn't do m = 0 mainly because before doing the homework I had been doing some recreational studying on the relationship between the square numbers and the sum of odd numbers, so 5 and 4 stood out to me almost immediately. Either way though, I believe that my response should have been a satisfactory answer to the problem.

Comment: I also think half-mark is unreasonable, even in homework. (It would be very unreasonable on a test.). You had started with a sentence $\varphi$, looked at $\lnot\varphi$, and showed using **an example** (not counterexample) showing the truth of $\lnot\varphi$, and hence the falsity of $\varphi$.  By the way, there was no need to go through the fuss of negating $\varphi$.

Comment: Expanding on Brian's comment, what would have been nice was to explain that 9 is not a prime because it is a square and also that that was not a coincidence: that you deliberately picked an odd square $3^2 = 9$, and then you took 9/2 = 4.5 and then you picked the two integers closer to this value, i.e., 4 and 5, in order to use the fact that the difference of the squares of two consecutive integers is equal to their sum, which in this case is clearly 9 because $4 + 5 = 4.5 + 4.5 = 9$, this would have been a nice way to justify your choice! In any case, I think your "proof" is correct.

Comment: Now I see your new comment and it seems that you DID use difference of squares of consecutive integers. The moral of the story: write MORE, let your teacher know what is going on in your mind!

Comment: Ok. I guess I will have to write more next time. In addition to this question, I received half-credit and no-credit on the other two problems, both of which I believe had responses which were just as valid to their problems as my response was to this particular problem.

Comment: Could you not have mentioned that the difference of *any* two squares is always factorable?

Comment: Comment to DJohnM: factorable does not imply composite, you want to use $n^2 - m^2 = (n-m) (n+m)$ but sometimes one of these factors (the first one for positive integers) is 1, and you obtain a prime, as in $4^2 - 3^2 = 7$.

Comment: My final comment is that it is possible that the teacher gave you only half-credit because he was thinking in a totally different solution, "orthogonal" to yours, and perhaps simpler. Of course, this does not justify what he did! He was possibly thinking in the case on NON-CONSECUTIVE, positive integers n and m, in which case by the factorization I just wrote in my previous comment, the difference of squares is ALWAYS composite, for all n and m. As I said, a teacher NEVER has to consider something wrong or incomplete just because it is a different approach that the one he had in mind!

Answer (score 0):

For all integers n,m; if $n > m, n^2−m^2$ is a prime number.

In order to disprove something, you only need to draw one example. For your case:
$5>4,$ but $25-16$ is $9$, which is quite obviously not prime. Therefore, it is not true that for all integers n,m; if $n > m, n^2−m^2$ is a prime number. QND.

Therefore, your teacher should have given you full credit for the problem. QED

Comment: In a low level course I'll expect students to show all details, e.g. $5^2-4^2 = 9 = 3\cdot3$, which is not prime.